# Android content provider query IN clause

Tags: android, sqlite

Is possible to use an IN clause for a content provider?

I am currently using

```
cursor = contentResolver.query(CONTENT_URI, PROJECTION, "field IN (?)", new String[] { argsBuilder.toString() }, null);
```

If i remove the `(?)` and just use `?` I get an error.

I get 0 count in my cursor.

If I type manually and execute the query in sqlite3 it works.

Help?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

When using the `IN` operator, you need to have one `?` separated by a comma per argument you provide in your `selectionArgs` array. E.g.:

```
String[] selectionArgs = {"red", "black"};
String selection = "color IN (?, ?)";
```

The following picks the right count and the proper `args`:

```
int argcount = 2; // number of IN arguments
String[] args = new String[]{ 1, 2 };
StringBuilder inList = new StringBuilder(argcount * 2);
for (int i = 0; i < argcount; i++) { 
    if(i > 0) {
        inList.append(",");
    }
    inList.append("?"); 
}
cursor = contentResolver.query(
   CONTENT_URI, 
   PROJECTION, 
   "field IN (" + inList.toString() + ")", 
   args, 
   null);
```

Comment: Thanks! I wanted to know if IN is supported or I have to do it like this.

Comment: Everything of genious is simple. Thank you,

Comment: How to use 2 different argument using IN clause?

Comment: For multiple arguments I'd suggest folding them into a single Object[] array.

Answer (score 3):

If your arguments are numbers only, this works as well:

```
Iterable args = ...; // any array, list, set, ... 
cursor = contentResolver.query(CONTENT_URI, PROJECTION, "field IN (" + TextUtils.join(",", args) + ")", null, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a code snippet from my application built in Kotlin, the params array is for illustration purposes only as the parameters come from elsewhere in the code.

The problem with most of the proposed solutions is that they result in the loss of the SQL injection prevention that the use of placeholders provides, so I only use an expression that returns an array of "?" and whose quantity matches the array of provided parameters and then becomes a comma separated String.

That way, the delivered string is a string of placeholders and not the parameters directly.

Sorry for my first answer write in spanish.

```
var params = arrayOf("1789","1787","1694","1784")
applicationContext.contentResolver.query(
    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
    null,
   "_ID IN (" +  Array(params.size) { "?" }.joinToString() + ")",
    params,
    null
)
```